# Photo upload not uploading files bigger than 2MB

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have a php file upload in place in which the forms target is an iframe.

It uploads files less than 2mb fine. But anything larger it will not upload. I cant see any reason behind this in the code.

```
<div id="upload_wrapper">

<img src="../images/logo.png" alt="logo5" width="" height="" style="padding:0px;" />
<h3>Profile picture upload</h3>

  <form id="upload" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="index.php" target="upload_target">
    <input name="folder" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $folder ?>"  />
    <input name="filename" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $filename ?>"  />
    <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" size="5120" id="uploaded_file"  />
    <input id="sent" name="sent" type="submit"  value="Upload" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="loading" style="background:url(ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat left; height:50px; width:370px; display:none;">
  <p style="margin-left:40px; padding-top:15px;">Uploading File... Please wait</p>
</div>
<div id="image_wrapper" style="display:none;"><p id="preview"></p></div>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" style="width:10px; height:10px; display:none"></iframe>
</div>
```

And heres the php upload code

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$targetFolder = $_POST['folder'] . "/";
$filename2 = $_POST['filename'];

if (!is_dir($targetFolder)) 
{
    mkdir($targetFolder, 0777);
}

    $tempFile = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) 
    {
        $uploadfile = $targetFolder. basename($filename2 .".".$fileParts['extension']);
         move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$uploadfile);
         $fileName = $uploadfile;
    }

    echo "<div id='filename'>$fileName</div>";

}
```

Comment: Probably because of the server/php configuration limiting POST data to 2MB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size just edit your php.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe changing your php server's configuration would help (example for 10MB):

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your php.ini configuration support large files. `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` also you can change the configuration temporary using `ini_set` before you handle the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it would work put it in your code and then try

```
 define ("MAX_SIZE","1000"); // put your max size value 
 $size=filesize($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);

 //compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
  if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
    {
echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
$errors=1;
     }
```

or else you have to edit in php.ini found in document root/php/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You can change your server setting. Look for the php.ini file and search "upload_max_filesize"