# move_uploaded_file not working for 2mb and more

Tags: php, file, upload

I wanted to upload files greater than 2MB and I have changed `php.ini` as follows :

```
upload_max_filesize=20M
post_max_size=30M
```

Restarting Apache updates `phpinfo()` but files greater than 2MB are not yet being uploaded. What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure that you updated `php.ini` for apache? Maybe you updated for `php.ini` for cli?

Comment: try changing max_execution_time in php.ini and also write permission of the folder in which you are uploading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you updated the right php.ini, some servers accept having a php.ini for a certain folder

Answer (score 1):

A similar question: [Photo upload not uploading files bigger than 2MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717766/photo-upload-not-uploading-files-bigger-than-2mb)

Basically you have to modify your php server's configuration as the link shows to you